# How can we safely upgrade SSH 7.4 to 7.8 on AmazonLinux2

Tags: upgrade, openssh, sshd, systemctl, amazon-linux

I have an SFTP server that runs on Amazon Linux 2 on AWS.

The current SSH version is OpenSSH_7.4p1, is it possible to safely upgrade this to version 7.8. If yes how can I get it done.

Since the SFTP server is already a production environment and has many users and applications connecting to it, I am worried if this upgrade might break anything.

I need to upgrade due to a limitation in the current version.

---

Update:

I was able to upgrade to the required version. But, my service file seems to not start the sshd service. It instead displays "sshd.service start operation timed out. Terminating."  However, the new ssh service starts and works when i manually execute /usr/sbin/sshd in the terminal.

Can some one please help me at this point. Any hints here ?

Comment: General principle: do it in preproduction and once it's validated, do it again in production

Comment: yes. I will be doing it in a clone environment. :)

Comment: hey, I was able to upgrade to the required version. However, my service file seems to not start the sshd service. It instead displays sshd.service start operation timed out. Terminating. It starts when i manually run /usr/sbin/sshd. Any hints here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. I followed the below blogs to complete and troubleshoot my openssh upgrade. I was doing it on amazon linux. However, I believe this should work on centos as well.

https://www.tecmint.com/install-openssh-server-from-source-in-linux/

https://blog.jonkimi.com/2020/04/17/Upgrade-openssh-server-on-Ubuntu/

http://blog.chinaunix.net/uid-28813320-id-5786956.html

Answer (score 0):

If there's an upgrade for CentOS available, you could simply run `dnf update` - I see no issues with that. Existing SSH sessions will not be terminated.

Comment: I will check if this too. However, mine is Amazon Linux. I had listed out available openssh  packages using yum and it showed below available packages

7.4p1-16.amzn2.0.6, 
7.4p1-21.amzn2.0.1

Comment: Your question contained the CentOS tag, so I presumed you were running CentOS. I can't help with Amazon Linux as I've no idea what this distro is and where to get packages for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded openssh 7.4 to 9.3 on amazon Linux 2 and followed the below steps for the same

```
  yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
  yum install pam-devel libselinux-devel
  tar zxvf openssh-9.3p1.tar.gz 
  cd openssh-9.3p1/
  ./configure 
  ls -l /usr/local/etc
  ./configure  --with-pam --with-selinux --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd/ --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh
   make
   make install
```

while running "make install" you will get the below error comment both the line and re-run the "make install"

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 77: Unsupported option GSSAPIAuthentication
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 78: Unsupported option GSSAPICleanupCredentials
```